# need help showing dates from mysql query using between

Tags: php, mysql

I need to show dates only from previous month, this month and next month but getting no results form this mysql query

```
$query = "SELECT *,
DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M') SHIFTDATEMONTH,
DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%e') SHIFTDATEDAY,
DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%W') SHIFTDATEWEEKDAY,
FROM record
WHERE user='".$usernamez."'
AND MONTH(created_at) BETWEEN 'MONTH(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)' AND 'MONTH(CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)'
AND YEAR(created_at) BETWEEN 'YEAR(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)' AND 'YEAR(CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)'
ORDER BY created_at ASC";
```

Comment: you want result for current , previous and next month or only current and previous?

Comment: need for current, previous and next. so three months

Comment: Try like this

select *
            from events
     where DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_created), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-09-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL -1 SECOND and date_created BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
     order by date_created desc

Comment: it did not work

Comment: can you share create sqlfiddel and send link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this this will work

```
select * from users where (YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) OR MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())AND YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) OR YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

[image]